# Devise mailer is not sending mails in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have set up a rails application on a company internal network. I use `Devise::Mailer` for registration confirmation, password recovery, etc. I also have my own mailer class derived from `ActionMailer::Base`. In a development environment both type of mailers work fine, but on a production environment only my custom mailer seems to work.

I both environments the mail configuration is the same:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'my.internal.ip.address', port: 80 }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://my.internal.ip.address"

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'internal.mail.server',
    :port                 => 25,
    :domain               => 'domain.name'
  }
```

This SMTP server does not require authentication.

In the `config/initializers/devise.rb` I have set the sender address like this:

```
  config.mailer_sender = "myaddress@domain.name"
```

I have tried to set the `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` to `:file` in the production environment. In this case mails sent from my custom mailer are written into files, but mails sent from the Devise mailer are not.

How can I make the Devise mailer work in production environment?

**Update**

I have copied the `config/environments/production.rb` file to `config/environments/development.rb` and it still works in development mode but still not in production mode.

Answer (score -1):

All configurations you have set in Development mode will then work in production mode, you need to reconfigure the default mailer url - I can't imagine `my.internal.ip.address` is a valid `host` in production. You should be changing this to the domain name or the ip where the application code is hosted.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. `my.internal.ip.address` is just a placeholder for an actual ip address.

Comment: In `config/initalizers/devise.rb` have you configured the class responsible to send mailers `config.mailer` and set `mailer_sender`? I really can't see anything in your configuration that wouldn't allow emails to send in prod

Comment: Yes, I have configured both.